# find and replace with sed command and regexp

Tags: regex, linux, sed, command

hi i'm trying to find and replace the link rel tags into a file with this command :

```
sed 's/(<link\b.+href=\")(?!http)([^\"]*)(\".*>)/someText/g'  www/file.html
```

but it doesn't work , could somebody help me please ? 
thank
one example that i want to do is :

replace all this links tags :

```
 <!-- Common app CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="less/med.ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="less/timeline.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="less/animate.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="less/magic.min.css" />

<!-- Common UI CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/app/common/less/common.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="less/sidebar.css" />

<!-- Specific App CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/app/timeline/less/timeline.css" />
```

with only this line :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/app/globa/less/global.css" />
```

Comment: sed won't support lookarounds. Use Perl instead.

Comment: `perl -pe 's/(<link\b.+href=\")(?!http)([^\"]*)(\".*>)/someText/g'  www/file.html`

Comment: i tried it now,  but nothing ! thank

Comment: post an example along with expected output. Why you're trying to parse html files with regex?

Comment: ok  i do it , i modified the question ;) thank

Comment: yes i'm trying to parse html file.

Comment: you want to replace ALL those line with 1 line only , what about comment and spac line (and where to add in file at first occurance, at last, ...) request is equivoque

Comment: the comments and white space are not a problem in this moment, i need to  put only one line instead of all lines, i need to put this :
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/app/globa/less/global.css" />

Comment: it work for me but i need to modify to put the correct path :

perl -0777pe 's/(<link\b.+href=\")(?!http)([^\"]*)(\".*?>)/someText/gs'

Comment: ok i need to replace all occurrences with a single line of text.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since sed won't support lookarounds, i suggest you to use  Perl instead.

```
perl -pe 's~(<link\b.+href=\")(?!http)([^\"]*)(\".*>)~\1js/app/globa/less/global.css" />~g' www/file.html
```

To save the changes made.

```
perl -i -pe 's~(<link\b.+href=\")(?!http)([^\"]*)(\".*>)~\1js/app/globa/less/global.css" />~g' www/file.html
```

Comment: i run the commad , not errors in output, but the file www/file.html is not modified is the same .

Comment: you need to add `-i` parameter to save the changes made.

Comment: it save but replace every link tags that it find  , i need convert all links tags in only one. thank

Comment: try `perl -0777pe  's/(<link\b.+href=\")(?!http)([^\"]*)(\".*?>)/someText/gs'`

Answer (score 0):

doing this with sed

```
sed -i backup.bak '/<link\b.\+href=\"/{/href="[^"]*http/!{s#\(<link .\+href="\).*#\1js/app/globa/less/global.css" />#}}' www/file.html
```

EDIT:

or

```
sed -i backup.bak '/<link\b.\+href=\"/{
/href="[^"]*http/!{
s#\(<link .\+href="\).*#\1js/app/globa/less/global.css" />#
}
}'
```

`backup.bak` is a backup of the original file with a .bak extension

Comment: what operating system are you using?

Comment: Is this GNU sed?to find out tyep "sed --version" in a shell

Comment: result : 

sed: illegal option -- -
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]

Comment: i get this error with your command :
sed: 1: "/<link\b.\+href=\"/{/hr ...": bad flag in substitute command: '}'

Comment: answer edited to try another way with sed..The answer given works with gnu sed which supports more features, I don't think this is in Yosemite...

Answer (score 0):

this is the final solution :

```
perl -i -0777pe 's/(<link\b.+href=\")(?!http)([^\"]*)(\".*?>)/<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text\/css\" href=\"www\/less\/global_bst.css\" \/>/gs' www/*.html
```

i hope that this code will be helpful to you too.
thanks a lot for the answers .